# What is the difference between Yautja and Super Yautja in Predators?

Tags: predator, predator-series, predators-2010

Can someone please explain to me the differences between Yautja and the Super Yautja seen in 'Predators'?

I've read that they are a sub-species, but how are they different, in the way they act, think, hunt etc.? And why are they in a blood feud with the regular Yautja?

Comment: Super Yautja cost £16 more on most monthly cellphone plans, but they have a bigger screen and optical image stabilisation.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predator_(alien)) there are two types of predators, the "Classic Predator" and the "Black Super Predators".

The Black Super Predators use quadrupedal hunting beasts and elaborate traps to hunt.

The Classic predator hunts in a more "traditional" manner.

The Super Predators are leaner and taller than the "classic" Predator, and they have longer faces, tighter armor, and more swept-back dreadlocks.

Comment: The Super's don't seem to follow the same honour system as the "Classics" either. For example they do not disarm to fight an unarmed opponent and seem to have no qualms about killing injured / sick prey

Comment: Interesting point, but there is that scene where hanzo challenges one to fight with blades, and one of them accepts the challenge...

Comment: Wikipedia is user generated content. Is there primary source evidence provided for any of those claims?

Comment: The imdb trivia section for the movie, has some of the same info, but not all. "The predators featured were of a different clan and not the original predator design seen in the other films." Should I delete this answer if the Wiki info isn't strong enough?

Comment: In one of the predator & alien novels ( Alien vs predator prey i beleive) female predators are much larger and more dangerous and do not hunt for sport in the same way, males do. Hunting for the smaller males is about status. That could have been part of the inspiration.

Comment: @John: one can imagine the Predator hunting stuff being the way their society keeps its mostly-useless males occupied, so that they don’t get in the way of the female Predators taking over the universe.

Answer (score 1):

### The comic series called them "Bad Blood"

While I am unsure, are they the same as the one presented in the movie, the "Predator" comic series presented similar concept [since 1993](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Predator:_Bad_Blood):

> Bad Blood is the phrase used for any Yautja that has turned against its own kind and severely violated aspects of the Yautja Honor Code - intentional or not.
>
> If the individual is found to have brought dishonor to his people and flees before accepting punishment, there can be no forgiveness according to Predator tradition. Other Predators are allowed to eliminate the outcasts on sight. Bad Bloods are never accepted back into Predator society. Wandering aimlessly, some Bad Bloods have been known to hunt and slay anything alive, including other Predators.
>
> Bad Bloods are seen as more hostile and "mentally unstable" Predators. These sadistic hunters still use skills taught to them by their brothers, but use them dishonorably and purely for their own personal gain

The "[Alien vs Predator"](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Bad_Blood_(Yautja)) wiki states that the "Super Predators" could be indeed a Bad Blood clan.